# Applicationuser in ViewComponent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I want to get Access to the applicationUser in my viewComponent. However, this doesn´t work like a normal class that inherits from "Controller".

Does anyone know how I can access the ApplicationUser from my ViewComponent?

```
public class ProfileSmallViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _Context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _UserManager;

    public ProfileSmallViewComponent(UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager, ApplicationDbContext Context)
    {
        _Context = Context;
        _UserManager = UserManager;
    }

    //GET: /<controller>/
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        //ApplicationUser CurrentUser = _Context.Users.Where(w => w.Id == _UserManager.GetUserId(User)).FirstOrDefault();
    //Code here to get ApplicationUser

        return View("Header");
    }
}
```

Comment: "this doesn´t work like a normal class that inherits from "Controller".". Can you be more explicit why this "doesn't work"? Are you getting an exception? If so, please add the exception details to your question.

Answer (score 3):

It works like a charm. Here's your example I just tested:

```
public class ProfileSmallViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public ProfileSmallViewComponent(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var users = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();
        return await Task.FromResult<IViewComponentResult>(View("Header", users));
    }
}
```

By the way If you need to get current user, you can simply use `GetUserAsync` method, there's no need to using `ApplicationDbContext` dependency:

```
ApplicationUser currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```