# ASP.NET MVC Application: I was wondering if you can retrieve the current user in a ViewComponent?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is the class I am currently working in, and I would to inject the current user here, is this possible?
As you can see below, I tried using a filter, but then my chart wouldn't show at all.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using projecten2.Models.Domain;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace projecten2.ViewComponents
{
    [ViewComponent(Name = "chartjs")]
    public class ChartJsViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        
        [ServiceFilter(typeof(KlantFilter))]
        [Authorize]
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke(Klant klant)
        {
            // Ref: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/


            
            
            string[] dataLabels2 = new string[6];
            int[] data = { 5, 8, 4, 12, 10, 5 };
            DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
            string.Format("dd mm `yy");
            DateTime date2 = new DateTime();
            for(int i = 5; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                date2 = date.AddDays(-7);
                dataLabels2[i] = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yy}", date2) + "-" + string.Format(" 
                {0:dd/MM/yy}", date);
                foreach(Contract c in klant.Contracten)
                    foreach(Ticket t in c.Tickets)
                    {
                        if (t.AanmaakDatum > date2)
                            data[i]+=1;
                    };
                date = date2.AddDays(-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146985/applicationuser-in-viewcomponent